# PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)) WHEN setting up notifications flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I am gettting error when i have implemented Firebase notificattions in App
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

Comment: Are you using Firebase in your project? Can you share pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. In my case, changing the version of `firebase_core_platform_interface` in `pubspec.lock` file resolved the issue.
It was like the following:

```
  firebase_core_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: firebase_core_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.4.3"
```

And I've changed it to the following:

```
  firebase_core_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: firebase_core_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.2.4"
```

After the change, don't forget to make `flutter clean`.